# Implicit conversion to a base class during construction

Tags: c++

The following example is given in 12.7/3:

```
struct A { };
struct B : virtual A { };
struct C : B { };
struct D : virtual A { D(A*); };
struct X { X(A*); };
struct E : C, D, X {
    E() : D(this), // undefined: upcast from E* to A*
                   // might use path E* → D* → A*
                   // but D is not constructed
                   // D((C*)this), // defined:
                   // E* → C* defined because E() has started
                   // and C* → A* defined because
                   // C fully constructed
    X(this) {      // defined: upon construction of X,
                   // C/B/D/A sublattice is fully constructed
    }
};
```

Rule for the example is the following:

> To explicitly or implicitly convert a pointer (a glvalue) referring to
>   an object of class X to a pointer (reference) to a direct or indirect
>   base class B of X, the construction of X and **the construction** of all
>   of its direct or indirect bases that directly or indirectly derive
>   from B **shall have started** and the destruction of these classes shall
>   not have completed, otherwise the conversion results in undefined
>   behavior.

In the case Standard provide we have the list of A-derived classes is `{B, D, C, E}`. The construction of `A`, `C` and `B` has completed. But the construction of `D` has started at the moment we need to upcast use `E* → D* → A*`. So why the behavior actual undefined?

Comment: The construction of `D` starts at the point `D`'s constructor is actually called, which is after the conversion takes place.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion to `A*` is an argument evaluation that's necessarily done before the result is passed to the `D` constructor. So the `D` construction has not yet started. As a counter-example, the construction of `E` *has* started at this time, and not yet completed.